# A definite integral about lacunary function.(And a calculation of a limit added.)

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

The original problem is

> $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x}{\ln x}(x + x^2 + x^{2^2}+ x^{2^3}+\cdots) dx$$

Now the problem has been solved through the tips from Mr. Nosrati. The solution is as follows:

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{\ln x}(x+x^2+x^{2^2}+\cdots) \, dx &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{\ln x} \, \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{2^n} \, dx \\ 
> &= -\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}e^{-(2^n+1)u} \, du \\
> &= -\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(2^n+1)u}-e^{-(2^n+2)u}}{u} \, du \\
> &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ln\frac{2^n+1}{2^n+2}(e^0-\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{-x}) \\
> &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ln\frac{1+2^{-n}}{1+2^{-(n+1)}} \\
> &= -\ln 3.
> \end{align}

And he put forward a new challenging question,that is to calculate

> $$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k+1}{2^k+2}$$

I have made a rough estimate of it as follows:

> $$\frac{1}{2e^{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}}<\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2+1}{k^2+2}<\frac{1}{2}$$

which is given by

> $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{k^2+2}{k^2+1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{k^2+1})< \prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{1}{k^2+1}}<\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{1}{k^2}}=e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}}<e^{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$

Comment: Please add some attempt. For instance, since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{\log x}x^n\,dx $ equals $\log\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ by Frullani's integral, your integral is the logarithm of an infinite product. Can you deduce which one?

Comment: I would also dare to remark that $$\prod_{k\geq 0}\frac{2^k+1}{2^k+2}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, you certainly have given the answer directly. The answer should be -ln3  through your analysis.

Comment: indeed. Then I propose a challenging variation: replace the exponents $2^k$ with $k^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How do you prove that the product equals $\frac13$? Please post an answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Szeto, We have $ \frac{2^k+1}{2^k+2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2^k + 1}{2^{k-1} + 1}$. Can you compute the partial product $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2^k+1}{2^k+2}$ from this?

Comment: @SangchulLee I’m once again amazed...

Comment: Sorry, I thought about it for a long time, but I didn't get the final answer. But I made a very loose estimate as  $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{k^2+2}{k^2+1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+\frac{1}{k^2+1})\le \prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{1}{k^2+1}}<\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{1}{k^2}}=e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}}<e^{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$ so I got $\frac{1}{2e^{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}}<\prod_{i=0}^{n}\frac{k^2+1}{k^2+2}<\frac{1}{2}$